# How are arXiv papers cited using IEEE citation style?

Tags: publications, citations, arxiv, citation-style, ieee

I have been trying to find an IEEE publication which cites an arXiv paper.

However, it seems that electrical engineers shy away from citing anything arXiv related.

I have been looking around for a while but couldn't find any, can anyone provide a reference to a sample IEEE paper that cites an arXiv paper IEEE style?

Comment: _it seems that electrical engineers shy away from citing anything arXiv related_ — Weird. When I did a Scholar search for arxiv, restricted to the ieee.org domain, close to 37k results were returned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used Zotero to generate the following citation in IEEE style (see original paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.06830)). You can manually duplicate it if you wish, but I *highly* encourage you to consider using a reference manager to make your life simpler.

> J. Nettelblad and C. Nettelblad, “CannyFS: Opportunistically Maximizing I/O Throughput Exploiting the Transactional Nature of Batch-Mode Data Processing,” arXiv:1612.06830 [cs], Dec. 2016.

Also see [here](https://arxiv.org/help/faq/references) for more info on how to create a reference to a specific arXiv paper/version.

Comment: HI I downloaded Zotero, and after downloading the PDF, I right click on the PDF and click on "Create Bio from item", but it tells me "The items you have selected contain no references. Please select one or more references and try again.". How do I generate the citation like you did?

Comment: @MachineLearningisnotGod: Try this -- [install the browser extension](https://www.zotero.org/download/) for Zotero. Then go to the arXiv webpage for the article and click "Save to Zotero". Should automagically download the paper and save all of the reference information :) Alternatively, you can manually enter it -- when you click on the PDF, you fill in the "Info" section on the right. But again, the browser extension makes this very easy (and works with a wide variety of sites!).

Comment: I see, it seems for some paper it just automatically generates like "R. Meir and D. Parkes, “On Sex, Evolution, and the Multiplicative Weights Update Algorithm,” arXiv:1502.05056 [cs], Feb. 2015.", but not for others. I tried it on two different pdfs, for one it just created biblio for me, the other says no reference info

Comment: @MachineLearningisnotGod: See qsp's answer. If you can get a .bib file, you can import that into Zotero and it should do the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

Papers in arXiv are indexed by DBLP, which provides, among other things, Bibtex entries for those papers. Copy the Bibtex entry into your .bib file, and that's it. Latex will do the rest.

Comment: DBLP is very reliable and a good source for any bibtex entries!

Answer (score 2):

A Google search on (ieee reference format arxiv) should find the IEEE guide.
https://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/IEEE-Reference-Guide.pdf
Search the guide for arxiv, which appears twice.

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you could quote the relevant portions. Also, the link may change any time in the future making the answer inaccessible.

Comment: In this guide, an ArXiv Paper is cited as follows: "S. Urazhdin, N. O. Birge, W. P. Pratt Jr., and J. Bass, “Current-driven  magnetic  excitations  in permalloy-based multilayer nanopillars,” 2003. [Online]. Available: arXiv:cond-mat/0303149."